# Can I restore a password from a keystore

Tags: java, android, passwords, keystore

During the first application publication I've signatured the app, and made a keystore. Since then I have forgotten the password. Now I have made a new version and understand that it'll be impossible to update the application because there will be new certificate and a conflict during the app installation. Can anyone suggest any tricks on how to solve this problem?

Comment: You could try really hard to remember the old password.  Where were you when you set it?

Comment: good job.. .you forget the important password :-) ....and the same time I am worried for this problem, I don't know the answer but looking for experts suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

This is an extremely common problem--either forgetting the password or losing the key. I'm sorry to say it, but there's nothing you can do that I'm aware of. The whole point of the key is to make sure that people cannot update the application without having the keystore and the password. :(

So now you have a published app and no way to update it. You'll have to publish the app again, under a new packaged name, then try to get people to change from the old app to the new app--which is tricky. Better to do it as soon as possible though, so as you get new users they're on the new app.

Comment: so it's impossible to decrypt keystore to get password? :'(

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking about a solutions..(that I read somewhere but not able to find that link)
don't know it works or not

1. Find a previous .apk file which is signed with certificate A (which password you lost)
2. Now sign this .apk file with new certificate B and upload on market.
3. Now upload new .apk file signed with certificate B and give a try... :)